# Rails Ajax Form Disable Submit Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a little trouble figuring out how to disable the submit button in rails when a form is submitted. It works fine with javascript disabled and the ':disable_with' symbol in the 'remote_form_for#submit' function but cannot figure it out when submitting via ajax. Any thoughts? Using rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: It's not clear what you intend to do with submit button while submitting through ajax. 
Do you intend to disable submit button until the request comes back? It would be helpful in suggesting a solution, if you could let us know what exactly do you intend to achieve by disabling submit.

Comment: Yes, I would like to disable the submit button when the user submits the form and re-enable when the ajax request is complete. I am trying to make it so the user cannot submit the form twice for the same submission (and I don't want to use validations to verify uniqueness since duplicate values are allowed in the database).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hide the submit button when the request is made and show a loading image while the request is running.  For example in a form_remote_tag:

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => "/some_url", 
:loading => "$('submit_span').toggle(); $('loading_span').toggle();", 
:complete => "$('submit_span').toggle(); $('loading_span').toggle();" do %>

-- FORM CONTENTS --

  <span id="submit_span">
    <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
  </span>
  <span id = "loading_span" style = "display: none;">
    <%= image_tag("loading.gif")%>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

When the request completes (Success OR Failure) you unhide the submit and hide the loading span.

More docs on the various callbacks:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002174